# How to get a reference to the enclosing application in a view

Tags: marionette

I'm using Backbone.Marionette and RequireJS. All my application objects are totally modular.

I want to use the enclosing Marionette.Application instance's `vent` object as an application wide global event bus. What I'd like to be able to do is trigger an event from `vent` in some sub ItemView/CollectionView/whatever, but as far as I can see there's no reference to the enclosing app instance in sub-views. Is that right?

I know I can `require()` the actual app instance into my view (being careful to avoid circular dependencies naturally), but as far as I can see that breaks my modules' encapsulation. If a generic ItemView has to `require()` a specific app module/instance then I can't use that ItemView with any other app that happens to be in my code base.

Surely it'd make sense for Marionette.Application to propagate a reference to itself throughout any regions/layouts/sub-views that are instantiated off it? That way global events could be triggered into the `vent` by any sub-view without it having to know about which concrete Marionette.Application implementation is the parent app?

Or have I missed something fundamental?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is covered in the wiki: https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/wiki/Using-marionette-with-requirejs

See the section on avoiding circular dependencies

Comment: I have no problem with avoiding circular dependencies, what I'm keen not to do is pull in a specific Marionette.Application instance. I want my sub views to be generic, and not coupled to a particular app ...

Comment: Aha, I see now ... I needed to look at the "Example with central vent" bit of that wiki page. Thanks.

Comment: yeah, that's the part i meant to reference. sorry about that :)